# In which class keep data loaded from web service?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've `ArrayList<Item>` loaded from web service. In which class should I keep it - in fragment, in activity, in application class or in some other way?

I'm asking because I want to keep a single instance of loaded data. I don't want to store it in DB or shared preferences, my application used only in online mode.

Comment: use a `Service` for that and bind to that service using "local bound service" pattern

Comment: Thank pskink. I thought about this solution. So I'll use it.